# Auto-completation of java doesn't work in atom

Tags: java, atom-editor

I'm having a problem with atom, the auto-complete with java doesn't work.

First of all, I have set atom to fully support Java, I've installed the following package:

- List item
- atom-ide-ui
- autocomplete-java-minus
- ide-java
- java-classpath-registry
- java-generator
- java-import-wiz
- java-plus

And obviously, I have enabled all the necessary core package to do write some code with java.

I've got an error that can help to find the issue, when I start the ide-ui it tells me this error

```
Classpath is incomplete. Only syntax error will be reported.
Eclipse JDT.
```

And its advice me to check this link https://github.com/atom/ide-java/wiki/Incomplete-Classpath-Warning for more information, but anyway, I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this
https://atom.io/packages/ide-java

Ide Plugin for Atom
or you can use Visual Studio Code, which is going to be an IDE, vsCode is batter than Atom and give a lots of feature with plugins

Might this help you :)

...... thinking about a change

Comment: I said that i've already download ide-java package.... Anyway i switched from vscode to Atom, only just for curiosoty, for some things i think is better.